# Validar checkbox en JQuery

Tags: jquery

Necesito ayuda, quiero comparar una variable (ejemplo `var num = 9`;) con el `value` de un `$(':checkbox');` sí coincide marcar el `checkbox`

Necesito referencias, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').focus()

  $('#search').on('keyup', function(){
    var search = $('#search').val()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '../../src/php/fin_pacant.php',
      data: {'search': search}
    })
    .done(function(resultado){
    var cadena1 = resultado;
    var res = cadena1.split(" ");
    if($(':checkbox').val(res))
      $(this).prop('checked',true);
     })
  })
})


<?php 

require_once 'conexion.php';

function search()
{
  $mysqli = getConnexion();
  $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
  $query = "SELECT antecedente FROM pac_antecedente WHERE paciente = '$search' ";
  $res = $mysqli->query($query);
  while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
         $cadena .=$row[antecedente].' ';
   }

  echo "$cadena";
}

search();

?>
```

De seguro alguien podría mejorar mi código, pero ya que es funcional me tomé la libertad de compartirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo podes realizar de la siguiente manera.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var check = $('#banner-message input:checkbox');
  var precio = 50;
  var res = $('#respuesta');
   if(check.val()==precio){
    check.attr("checked", "checked");
    res.html('Si');
  }
     else{
      res.html('No');
  }
 })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/feq17sbh/

Lo que hice fue obtener los input con checkbox. Luego crear la variable para validar si es = y un plus para modificar la respuesta. Si el valor del checkbox = a la variable, se marca. Sino, no.

Se puede mejorar.